# how to make infinite scroll in will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying  to make infinite scrolling but I don't know why it won't work 
_allposts.html.erb parial

```
<% @posts.each do |f| %>
    <div class="iterate">
   <%= f.text %>
   <%= f.image %> 
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

posts controller :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    end
...
```

end

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need some `ajax`, `js` or `jQuery`, or `coffee` code and some partials, if I will write this then this will very large because you need a full tutorial.

This is a very generic question because you need to follow a deep tutorial for this, you did not write anything for infinite scroll, if you have to try then we have to point out where is the problem, you did not that that's why you follow full tutorial and then apply this then if you will stack for any stage then we will help for this.

[**This Tutorial**](https://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/)

[**This Tutorial Repo**](https://github.com/bodrovis/SitePoint-InfiniteScroll)

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy to go making "yourself"(even though a copy paste will work) then you could [use this gem](https://github.com/PlanBCom/will_paginate_infinite)

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'will_paginate_infinite'
```

**Then run**

```
$ bundle install
```

Add to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
*= require will_paginate_infinite
```

And javascript to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require will_paginate_infinite
```

Then use the gem's renderer

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: WillPaginateInfinite::InfinitePagination %>
```

Comment: I tried rails infinite scrollling before but didn't do anything i don't know why