# How to speed up a rails controller queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

My app seams to be getting bogged down. Can someone can help me optimize this controller code to run faster? Or point me in the right direction.
I'm trying to display a list of customers which are defined by active is true and a list of potential customers which active is false. Archived customers are archived true.
Thank you.

```
if current_user.manager?
  get_customers = Customer.where(:archived => false)
  @cc = get_customers.where(:active => true)
  @current_customers = @cc.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  @count_current = @current_customers.count

  @pc = get_customers.where(:active => false)
  @potential_customers = @pc.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  @count_potential = @potential_customers.count
end
```

**How does this look for improving speed?**

model

```
scope :not_archived, -> { where(:archived => false) }
  scope :current_customers, -> { where(:active => true).not_archived }
  scope :potential_customers, -> { where(:active => false).not_archived }
  scope :archived_customers, -> { where(:archived => true) }
```

Controller

```
 @current_customers = Customer.current_customers.includes(:contacts,:contracts)
```

View

```
link_to "Current Clients #{@count_current.size}"
```

Comment: it depend what exactly you want, but right now their serious issue with your code, you are retrieving full list of customer, that mean it will take too much memory, than you are queries it. First solution would be use paginate, it will give you total numbers, and return just limited 10 records, but than you won't be able to use :active => true! so try to think what exactly you have to show on your view, and modify records to get only that stuff with includes, joins and other selecting specific query. Another technique can be to check database side what query is create and use explain query.

Answer (score 2):

You may find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842918/how-to-make-infinite-scroll-in-will-paginate-gem)

As @Gabbar pointed out and I will add to it, your app right now is **eager-loading** (opposite of **lazy-loading**) which means that you are loading more from the database than needed. What we need to do is optimize but that totally depends on your use-case.

Whatever the use-case, you can do a few common things to make things better:
You can implement pagination (there are gems for it and you can do it yourself too) or infinite scrolling. In this case, you will be loading a set amount of records from db at first but as soon as user wants more, either they will scroll down or click 'next' button and your action will be called again but with an increment in the page number which means get the next set of records.

Implementing based on scroll involves JS and the view-height etc. but pagination is much simpler.

**Gems:**

[kaminari gem](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari)

[infinite-pages](https://github.com/magoosh/jquery-infinite-pages)

**Using `includes`**

One more thing you must do is, use include in query if your records are related. Using include is tricky but very very helpful in time-saving. It will fetch the related needed record together in one go from database unlike your code going to and fro database multiple times. Fetching from database takes a lot of time as compared to fetching from RAM.

```
@users = User.all.includes(:comments) #comments for all users brought along with users but saved in RAM for future access.
@comments = @users.map(&:comments) # no need to go to db again, just RAM.
```

**Using `scopes` in models:**

Creating scopes in models helps too. In your case, you should create scopes like this:

```
  scope :archived_customers, -> { where('archived IS false') }
  scope :potential_customers, -> { where('active IS false') }

  **OR**

  scope :archived_customers, -> { where(:archived => false) }
  scope :potential_customers, -> { where(:active => false) }
```

Comment: About the `includes`: What helps me during development is the "bullet" gem which (most of the time correctly) points out where includes are missing or are superfluous.

Comment: How does this look for improving speed?

model
  scope :not_archived, -> { where(:archived => false) }
  scope :current_customers, -> { where(:active => true).not_archived }
  scope :potential_customers, -> { where(:active => false).not_archived }
  scope :archived_customers, -> { where(:archived => true) }

      @current_customers = Customer.current_customers.includes(:contacts,:contracts)

View
link_to "Current Clients #{@count_current.size}"

Answer (score 1):

Loading all the available records in a single query can be very costly. Moreover, a user may be interested only in a couple of the most recent records (i.e., the latest posts in a blog) and does not want to wait for all records to load and render.

There are couples of ways to sort out this problem

example#1 implementation of [Load More](https://gist.github.com/zolzaya/7211962)

example#2 implementation of [Infinite Scrolling](https://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/)

example#3 implementation of [pagination](https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/pagination-in-rails-and-how-to-implement-go-to-page-fun)